# QBO API V3.0 SSL Certificates issue with Intuit server?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

We are experiencing an issue today which looks like a problem with Intuit's server SSL certificates.

None of our requests via the API goes through.

Here is an example:

The request URI is:

https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/1063929550/query?query=SELECT+*+FROM+Preferences+STARTPOSITION+1+MAXRESULTS+1

and the response we get is:

hostname in certificate didn't match: quickbooks.api.intuit.com != fmsoffline-prod.intuit.com OR internal.workplace.intuit.com OR sg.qbo.intuit.com OR www.intuitloanfinder.com OR appcenter.intuit.com OR shard04.services.intuit.com OR qbpurchasingcenter.intuit.com OR qbo.intuit.com OR shard03.services.intuit.com OR www.apps.intuit.com OR qdc.qbo.intuit.com OR fmsoffline-prod.intuit.com OR ca.qbo.intuit.com OR services.intuit.com OR datasync.intuit.com OR intuitmarket.intuit.com OR lvdc.qbo.intuit.com OR go.qbo.intuit.com OR workplace.intuit.com OR accounting.quickbooks.com OR shard01.services.intuit.com OR www.intuitmarket.com OR uk.qbo.intuit.com OR datasync4.intuit.com OR easysaver.intuit.com OR datasync2.intuit.com OR shard02.services.intuit.com OR ilf.intuit.com OR apps.intuit.com OR datasync3.intuit.com

I've tried to create an incident but the site is down, and when navigating to the support site the browser warned that the site didn't have a valid certificate. So perhaps all is due to an issue (expiry?) with the SSL certificates.

Thanks
Fernando

Comment: This is most probably related to our service outage. Please wait till this is resolved.

Comment: This is resolved. Let us know if you are still facing issues?

Comment: It is resolved. Thanks